# Using jQuery to Populate a Text Field Based on Checkboxes ID?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

### Context

I'm trying to build an answer to this [WordPress question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53803/12615).

I'm generating dynamic checkboxes in the media upload thickbox window. And they should serve to populate a text field where the user can copy/paste its value.

The final output of the text field is the *include* attribute in this shortcode `[gallery include="23,39,45"]`.

Mainly, I need a helping hand to build this last part: Checkbox -> Populate/Unpopulate Text Field...

---

### Layout

1. Dynamic checkboxes
2. Point of insertion of the text field (after the last `<tr>` shown in the console)
3. Text field to be populated, should be **include="** + CheckBoxID1 <sup>comma</sup> CheckBoxID2 <sup>comma</sup>  etc + **"**

   [image]

---

### Actual Code

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_head-media-upload-popup', 'wpse_53803_script_enqueuer' );

function wpse_53803_script_enqueuer() {
    if( $_GET['tab'] == 'gallery' ) 
    {
        ?>
            <style>#media-upload th.order-head {width: 5%} #media-upload th.actions-head {width: 10%}</style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    
                /* Iterate through the media items */
                $('.filename.new').each(function(i,e){
                    var id = $(this).next('.slidetoggle').find('thead').attr('id').replace(/media-head-/, '');
                    var filename = $('<label>Add to gallery list <input type="checkbox" name="gal-item-'+id+'" id="gal-item-'+id+'" value=""  /></label>').insertBefore($(this));
                    filename.css('float','right').css('margin-right','40px');

                    filename.id = id; // PROBLEM: not sure how to do this in Javascript
                    
                    // BUG: the alert is being fired twice
                    filename.click(function() {
                        alert('Handler for img id = '+filename.id+' called.');
                    });
                });                 
            });
            </script><?php
    }
}
```

---

### Missing Parts

- Create a dynamic text field to be populated.
- Solve the problem and the bug noticed in the comments.
- Make the `filename.click(function()` build the desired string inside the text field.

Comment: +1 for a nice definition of the problem. Albeit lengthy.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - Yep, I have a verbose(?), verbatim(?), problem... (question for english.stackexchange?).. and seen/answered many problematic, difficult to understand, questions... Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using something similar to this

```
 $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"][name^="gal-item"]',function(){
    var checkedIds = $('input[type="checkbox"][name^="gal-item"]:checked')
                       .map(function(){
       return parseInt($(this).prop('name').replace(/gal-item-/,''));
    }).get();

    $('#shortcode').val('include="'+checkedIds.join(',')+'"');

});
```

You can replace `document` with any `closer static container` which you have to find by inspecting the add media markup.    ​
And You have find a element where you want to add the input field, add it like

```
$('<span>[gallery</span><input type="text" id="shortcode" /><span>]</span>')
 .appendTo(TARGETIDORCLASS);
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/HsGdX/2/)

And based on this your rewritten code would be something like

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
     //add input field
     $('<span>[gallery</span><input type="text" id="shortcode" /><span>]</span>')
 .appendTo(TARGETIDORCLASS);
    //bind checkbox change handler


     $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"][name^="gal-item"]',function(){
         var checkedIds = $('input[type="checkbox"][name^="gal-item"]:checked').map(function(){
       return parseInt($(this).prop('name').replace(/gal-item-/,''));

    }).get();

    $('#shortcode').val('include="'+checkedIds.join(',')+'"');

    });


    /* Iterate through the media items */
    $('.filename.new').each(function(i,e){
        var id = $(this).next('.slidetoggle')
                        .find('thead')
                        .attr('id')
                        .replace(/media-head-/, '');
       var filename = $('<label>Add to gallery list <input type="checkbox" name="gal-item-'+id+'" id="gal-item-'+id+'" value=""  /></label>')
              .insertBefore($(this));
       filename.css('float','right').css('margin-right','40px');

                });                 
            });
```

This should work. I am in a hurry, couldn't test much, check and let me know if you find any error, I would love to fix those.

Comment: Hey, this working demo seems pretty goood.. will have to really test tomorrow, thanks for the input!

Comment: May I have the reasons for down vote please? I invested half an hour on this pausing my work, and down vote after that isn't great. Please at least care to comment the reason so I can correct myself.

Comment: Joy, I upvoted you from -1 and I see it is -1 again... This Stack is **much more wild** then WordPress', wow.. Downvotes without comments? No comments! *(PS.: amazed at having received 3 upvotes in minutes..!)*

Comment: @brasofilo, I dont mind down voting anyone can down vote, if they take a moment and tell me the reason So that I dont do it again in future. I am a newbie and try to do rnd and answer question with a hope of learning new things from the rnd. Down votes without comment is discouraging.

Comment: **Olé!** Works like a charm, Joy! Very well done, much appreciated!! I'll research your profile and ++ where due :)

Comment: @brasofilo, Thanks. I have been learning a lot by doing rnds, while answering question. :)